# finding the average element by value in array

Tags: arrays

I have an array of integer elements. I need to find an average element by value.The quantity of elemets is odd and elemets can't duplicate. 
For example, i have an array A[5]={100, 43, 55, 34, 68}. So the element would be 55. The problem is that i need to preserve my array and i can't use any extra arrays, also i can't sort this array.

I was thinking about finding the average value of array and then find the nearest element to this value, but for really different numbers it won't work.

Comment: Google for "Median algorithm".

Comment: you may refer http://discuss.codechef.com/questions/1489/find-median-in-an-unsorted-array-without-sorting-it

Comment: You want to find its **median**, not **average**.

Comment: @herohuyongtao - Mean, median and mode are all *types* of average, strictly speaking :)

Comment: @KarlNicoll You mean "general speaking". :)

Comment: @herohuyongtao - Haha indeed I do!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform this task while using constant amount of memory (I assume that's what you mean as you mentioned no additional arrays are allowed), then performing this task in linear time is impossible.

More so, if the array is to be untouched and in-place ordering is not allowed, it's also impossible to perform in `O(nlogn)` time.

You are left with the naive approach:

```
int NaiveFindMedian(int[] A){
    int i, j, count;

    for (i = 0; i < A.length){
        count = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < A.length; j++)
            if (A[j] < A[i]) count++;

        if (count == (A.length-1)/2) return i;
    }
}
```

Obviously it's expensive computational (`O(n^2)`), but that's the price of using `O(1)` memory. if you allow `O(n)` memory, you can perform this task in `O(n)` time.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to find Average value of array and Nearest value in array element

```
import java.util.Scanner;


    public class AA {
        public static void main(String[] args) {


    float b=0,j = 0;
    float c;
    int l = 0;
    Scanner s1=new Scanner(System.in);
    int x=s1.nextInt();
    int[]a =new int[x];
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {
         a[i]=s1.nextInt(); 
    }
      for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
      {
         b=b+a[i]; 
      }
      float g=a.length;
      c=b/g;
      System.out.println("Average="+c);
      for(int k=0;k<a.length;k++)
        {
            for(int h=1+k;h<a.length;h++)
            {
                if(b>a[h])
                {   
                    b=a[h];
                    int temp=a[h];
                    a[h]=a[k];
                    a[k]=temp;
                }
            }       
        if(l<a.length-1)
        {
                b=a[++l];

        }
        }
      for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
      {
         if(c<a[i])
         {
             float v=a[i]-c;
             float s=a[i-1]-c;
             if(s<0)
             {
                  j=s*(-1);
             }
             if(v==j)
                     {
                         System.out.println("Array Element NearBy="+a[i-1]+" or "+a[i]);
                     }
             else if(v>j)
             {
                 System.out.println("Array Element NearBy="+a[i-1]); 
             }
             else
             {
                 System.out.println("Array Element NearBy="+a[i]); 
             }
             break;
         }
      }
        }

    }
```